# How To test Another class function is static function call

Tags: android, powermockito

I am having a Utils Class which creates a ToneGenerator object and call starttone function. Now i need to write test case for that . Does someone know how to do that

I can mock static object and verify call but don't how to verify starttone function

```
public static void playError(final int volume) {`
                ToneGenerator toneGen1 = `new`ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, volume);`
                toneGen1.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_SOFT_ERROR_LITE, DURATION);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(DURATION * 2);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // nothing to do here
                }
                toneGen1.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_SOFT_ERROR_LITE, DURATION);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to call function through class name directly,means for static method no need to make object to call them.
so if you want to verify any method that is it static,call that method through class directly.
in your case call startTone like this,

```
  ToneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_SOFT_ERROR_LITE, DURATION);
```

if it executed successfully then startTone is static.

Comment: but it is not a static method